# The attached email appears in compose mode when open in desktop Outlook

Tags: javascript, outlook, exchangewebservices

I attached an email message to a new message before sending it. But, the received attachment is editable on Outlook Desktop and is not on Outlook web. It means that when I try to open the attachment, it appears in compose mode in Outlook desktop. I used createItem to create and send the message, and ItemAttachment to put the attachment. I don't understand why it works on the web and not on the desktop. 
Here is the part of code which make the attachment:

```js
var soap = '<m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">'+
                   '    <m:Items>' +
                   '        <t:Message>' +
                   '            <t:Subject>' + subject + '</t:Subject>' +
                   '            <t:Body BodyType="HTML">' + body + '</t:Body>' +
                   '            <t:Attachments>' +
                   '                <t:ItemAttachment>' +
                   '                    <t:Name>' + attachmentName + '</t:Name>' +
                   '                    <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>' +
                   '                    <t:Message>' +
                   '                        <t:MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">' + attachmentMime + '</t:MimeContent>' +
                   '                    </t:Message>' +
                   '                </t:ItemAttachment>' +
                   '            </t:Attachments>' +  
                   '            <t:ToRecipients><t:Mailbox><t:EmailAddress>' + to + '</t:EmailAddress></t:Mailbox></t:ToRecipients>' +
                   '        </t:Message>' +
                   '    </m:Items>' +
                   '</m:CreateItem>';
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the PR_MessageFlags extended property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160304(v=exchg.80).aspx on the attachment to make it appear sent eg

```
<t:Message>
  <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>
  <t:Subject>subject</t:Subject>
  <t:Body BodyType="HTML">body</t:Body>
  <t:IsRead>false</t:IsRead>
  <t:ExtendedProperty> 
    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="3591" PropertyType="Integer" /> 
    <t:Value>1</t:Value> 
  </t:ExtendedProperty>
</t:Message>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, it works wery well but without <subject> and <body>.